# How can i deny PROPFIND requests for a specific route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, icalendar, propfind

When a propfind request appears I want to return my own error message with status code 404. Currently this error message appears:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PROPFIND] "/ical/12345622d73"):
```

Comment: When an `ActionController::RoutingError` is raised in the production environment then Rails should per default return a proper 404 error. Your app does not do that?

Comment: My app does that but i would like to intercept this and raise my own error message.